# F# Embedded resource is ignoring subfolder structure

Tags: f#, embedded-resource

I am trying to embed resources (.xsd) to my project. The folder structure is as follows

```
- Project
 project.fsproj
 - subfolder
     - v1
         file.xsd
     - v2
         file.xsd
```

This file is embedded as a recourse and I would expect that I can access the files as follows {Namespace}.subfolder.v1.file.xsd and replace v1 with v2 if I want to load v2. However, my resources are being embedded without any reference to namespace or folder structure. When I call GetManifestResourceNames() it tells me that there is only one file

```
file.xsd
```

If I change v2/file.xsd -> v2/file2.xsd output for GetManifestResourceNames is

```
file.xsd
file2.xsd
```

What I expected the names would be

```
{Namespace}.v1.file.xsd
{Namespace}.v2.file.xsd
```

Project is part of a much larger solution that may be causing this in its build process. I can't reproduce the behaviour with an isolated project. But I am not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Is this .NET Framework or .NET Core? I cannot repo on .NET Core. If I had to guess I'd put my money on your fsproj not including the files correctly? Can you update your question with the contents of your fsproj?